# Generating randomized objects in a loop in c++

Tags: c++, random

I have a person object class which is made up of name, address, and phone number object classes. The name, address, and phone number are randomly generated.

The user selects how many random people to generate and a function is called that generates them with a loop and stores them in a vector:

```
vector<Person> pV;  //vector of people

for(int i = 0; i < num; i++){
    Person x; //create new person object x
    pV.push_back(x) //add to vector of people
    cout << pV[i].getName();  //print for text
}
```

The problem is, all the objects generated are identical (same name, address, etc). If I generate a new list during the same session, a person with different information gets generated but they'll still all be identical.

I know this can happen in Java if you use static when randomizing... I'm not sure of the equivalent in C++.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Using just the name the person class is set up as follows:

Person class is set up as follows:

```
class Person{
public:
    Person();
private:
    Name name;
};

Person::Person(){
    Name name;
}
```

The name class with random name generation is:

```
class Name{
public Name();
    string generateName();
private:
    string name;
};

Name::Name(){
    Name = generateName();
}

string Name::generateName(){
    srand(time(NULL));
    string Names[5] = {"a", "b", "C", "d", "e"};
    int randomName = rand() % 5;
    return Names[randomName];
}
```

Comment: Please give a [mcve]. Since you haven't even shown the code which constructs the random people, how can anyone know why it doesn't behave the way that you wish it behaved?

Comment: Make certain you are not resetting or reseeding the random number generator in the `P` constructor.

Comment: @JohnColeman Sorry, I've added a minimal version of my person and name class.

Comment: @user4581301I'm not positive on what you mean, but I think I probably am. How would I go about fixing that?

Comment: Do this: `srand(time(NULL));` only once. Put it up near the top of your `main` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `srand(time(NULL));` every name you generate reseeds the random number generator. If names are generated too quickly, under the 1 second resolution of `time`, the same seed will be used and the same sequence of random numbers will be generated.

Comment: @Strobe00 If someone answers a question in a way that solves your problem, you should mark that answer as accepted.